# Xamarin forms Prism Refit

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

My project crashes when I try to initialize Refit in my Base ViewModel. I want to reuse it in my other view models inheriting from my Base View Model but when I launch the project it crashes when trying to navigate to a page

`protected IRestFulService _restFulService = RestService.For<IRestFulService>(HttpUrl.BaseUrl);`

Comment: Why does it crash?  What is the exception causing it?  Have you tried adding any exception handling to catch it?

Comment: I've resolved it, the issue was that in my interface I was not returning a Task